# apex:detail tag without sharing

Tags: apex, sharing, detail

I have a controller class without sharing. On the VF page I have an apex:detail tag where I've set the subject ID.  This causes an insufficient privileges error.

I'm guessing setting the subject ID of the apex:detail causes it to requery the record outside the scope of my without sharing controller. Is that what's going on? Is there any way to force it into without sharing?

UPDATE: this also seems to apply to a chatter:feed tag referencing an record ID even if the controller is without sharing.

Comment: Is the Vf page accessible to user?

Comment: Yes the user can see the page and the rest of the content fine if I remove the apex:detail tag

Comment: Then you are right i feel.The Subject Id is troubling you.

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce and Apex Code are two distinct layers. It's important to remember this. Even a page running "without sharing" in the controller will still respect field level visibility on the page, for example. You can't bypass Visualforce's security, but you can trick it by querying the data in a no-sharing zone and rendering the data in non-`apex:outputField`/`apex:inputField` tags.

Comment: Hm, so how would VF know without some type of controller layer? I assumed for tags like apex:detail it was still utilizing a controller to execute the query it was just part of system code that is not accessible.

Comment: Visualforce will use the standard controller for the page, or construct a standard controller from a sobject passed into the detail's `subject` attribute. In either case, that code is a system library that always runs in user mode (with sharing, field level security, etc, in place). This design helps limit data exposure that would otherwise occur from careless controller design. Reckless design, however, is still not covered.